# Need to show JSON data in single line, humanly readable

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I used [this library](https://github.com/gigobyte/HLTV) to made a simple console-style scorebot that outputs the logs of CS:GO live match (eg. frags, assists, player connecting into the server), I made this code that outputs all the logs in a JSON style object:

```
const HLTV = require('hltv').default
HLTV.connectToScorebot({

    id: 2349500,
    onLogUpdate: (data) => {

        console.log(data.log)
    }

})
```

And the output in console is a lot of logs like this, which is correct:

```
[
  {
    Kill: {
      killerName: 'kr1vda',
      killerNick: 'kr1vda',
      killerSide: 'TERRORIST',
      victimNick: 'nonick',
      victimName: 'nonick',
      victimSide: 'CT',
      weapon: 'ak47',
      headShot: true,
      eventId: 2151088609,
      victimX: -1728,
      victimY: -1182,
      killerX: -1861,
      killerY: -1165,
      killerId: -1,
      victimId: 10732
    }
  }
]
```

But I want to have a single line output like 'PlayerX killed PlayerY with ak47', so I made this:

```
const HLTV = require('hltv').default
HLTV.connectToScorebot({

    id: 2349500,
    onLogUpdate: (data, done) => {
        const event = Object.keys(data)[0]
        const eventData = data[event]

        if (event === 'Kill') {
            console.log(`${eventData.killerNick} killed ${eventData.victimNick} using ${eventData.weapon}`)
        }
    }
})
```

Which should print a single line string when a kill occurs, but instead of that the output is empty, nothing ever shows up.
I know it's not hard but I'm not an expert and I would be grateful if someone could help me fix this please. Thanks

Comment: what is the output if you do `console.log(data)` instead of `console.log(data.log)`?

Comment: { Kill: [Object] },
    { Kill: [Object] },
    { Kill: [Object] },
    { Kill: [Object] },
    { Kill: [Object] },
    { Kill: [Object] },
    { RoundStart: {} },
    { RoundEnd: [Object] },
    { BombDefused: [Object] },
    { Kill: [Object] },
    { Assist: [Object] },
    { Kill: [Object] },

Comment: That happens in the first code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to grab the event from data.log

```
const HLTV = require('hltv').default
HLTV.connectToScorebot({

    id: 2349500,
    onLogUpdate: (data, done) => {
        const event = Object.keys(data.log[0])[0]
        const eventData = data.log[0][event]

        if (event === 'Kill') {
            console.log(`${eventData.killerNick} killed ${eventData.victimNick} using ${eventData.weapon}`)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but with your code I now get that error

Comment: I've updated the code to use data.log, try it again

Comment: keep in mind that this will only grab the first event, you need to use a for loop to grab all events https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp